# test relatively simple custom hook that use useeffect and setTimeout

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am writing the jest test cases from few days but not sure how to write it for the custom hooks which uses the time, help me to write the test case for the below

```
useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setCurrentAdIndex((prevIndex) => {
        let nextIndex = prevIndex + 1;
        if (prevIndex === ads?.length - 1) {
          setShouldShowAds(false);
          nextIndex = -1;
        }
        return nextIndex;
      });
    }, visibilityTimeOutInMillis);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [ads, visibilityTimeOutInMillis]);
```

Here is my test case skeleton:

```
const mockRenderWidgetComponent = renderWidgetComponent as jest.Mock;
const mockUseState = useState as jest.Mock;
const mockUseEffect = useEffect as jest.Mock;
const setShouldShowAds = jest.fn();

beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();

    mockUseState.mockReturnValue([false, setShouldShowAds]);
});

describe("AdsPanel widget tests", () => {
    const renderer = (
        props: Widget<AdsPanelWidgetData> = ADS_PANEL_WIDGET_DATA
    ): ShallowWrapper => shallow(<AdsPanelWidget {...props} />);

// Add the test cases here the 

});
```